# What is Wrong with My Concatenation Operation?

Tags: c, pointers, string-concatenation

I was trying to implement `strcat()`, so I came up with this code. But, I don't know what is wrong with it? It's giving me segmentation fault.

I was thinking that this might be a memory allocation mess? Is that it? How can I fix it without using `malloc()`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *strcat(char *s,char *d){

 while(*s++ != '\0') ;
 while(*s++ = *d++) ;

 *s = '\0';

 return s;
}

int main(){

char s[20]= "source";
char d[20]= "dest";

printf("%s\n",strcat(s,d));

return 0;
}
```

I have to concat `d` ahead of `s`.

Comment: so i have to use malloc?

Comment: No, it is enough to define `s` so that it will hold both strings plus the null terminator: `char s[11] = "source"`, for example.

Comment: Also you confused source and destination: you add destination to the source.

Comment: You're also returning `s`, which is pointing at the final terminator so the printing will never succeed. Also the name of the function isn't valid, that's a reserved name.

Comment: @unwind the name of function is okay because there is a different return type look close other than library function and yes i noticed that s

Comment: @user3236961 No. The return type is the same [see the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat), but that doesn't matter since C isn't polymorphic. Names beginning with `str` are reserved [see here, for instance](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html).

Comment: @unwind anyway my program compiled without walling warnings in gcc, anyway thanks for noticing  s was pointing at the terminator , thats where the whole thing went wrong, i fixed it .

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat look at the code i am adding destination to source

Comment: @user3236961 Many programs can compile and still be wrong, I'm trying to help here. :)

Comment: You are null-terminating twice, potentially writing out of bounds.

Comment: @user3236961 You copy chars from d (destination) to s (source): `*s++ = *d++`. Just swap parameter names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 20

char *strocat(char *s,char *d){

 char *temp = s;

 while(*s++ != '\0');
 *--s;
 while(*s++ = *d++);

 *s = '\0';

 return temp;
}

int main(){

char s[SIZE] = "source";
char d[SIZE] = "dest";

printf("%s\n",strocat(s,d));

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The strings are in read only memory
2. The string `s` will not be long enough

To fix:

```
   ...
   #define S_STR "source"

   char *d= "dest";
   char *s= S_STR;
   s = malloc(strlen(s) + strlen(d) + 1);
   strcpy(s, S_STR);
   printf("%s\n",strcat(s,d));
   free(s);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: what if i pass an char array?

Comment: Yes - just noticed that myself

Answer (score 1):

The s, d are string constants! You should never do such  things.
have a big array like char s[100], copy source to it, and then use your concatenation. Remember that s should have room to accomodate the content of d!

Answer (score 0):

The strings s and d you declared are constant string literals,You can't modify them.
you should declare two char arrays and make sure the one you are copying to is big enough to hold the other.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *strcat(char *s,char *d)
{
    //Get length of s string
    size_t len = strlen(s);

    //declare new pointer and assign it the value of s
    char *ptr = s;

    //move the pointer to the end of the string
    ptr += len;

    //copy contentes of d string to s string
    while( *d != '\0' )
    {
        *ptr++ = *d++;
    }

    *ptr = '\0';

    //return s
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    //make sure s array length is big enough to accomodate d string
    char s[50] = "source";

    char d[] = "dest";

    printf("%s\n",strcat(s,d));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is code, not an answer. It can be improved by addressing the questions in the OP